# What's the difference between "to brag" and "to boast"

Tags: word-choice, differences, synonyms

Sometimes these words are used interchanged in just two consecutive sentences, therefore I don't expect there to be a big and obvious difference. Nevertheless, since people use the English language, words get connotations and that's what I'm asking for.

I recognised that "*boast*" is being used more often than "*brag*", see [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=boast%2C%20brag&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=prahlen), and Google Search by itself for that.

Comment: They are synonyms - http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=boast - http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=brag

Comment: They can be synonyms, but I can see _boast_ being used in a positive sense, where _brag_ is (almost?) exclusively _negative_: “This company boasts twenty years' experience in the field” is certainly not bad, but if this company _brags_ about their experience, it is certainly negative.

Comment: In addition to @oerkelens’ comment, my instinctive gut feeling is that if you’re talking about things that aren’t true (“Yeah, I have three PhD’s and designed the Apollo 11 with one hand behind my back”), then you’re _bragging_ more than _boasting_. This is particularly true if the verb is not qualified: you can either brag or boast _about_ things that never happened, but if you’re just bragging/boasting (full stop), then I would usually assume that _boast_ is about stuff that’s real, whereas _brag_ might go either way. [cont’d-->]

Comment: [-->cont’d] In other words, if someone says, “Don’t worry about X, he’s just _b****ing_”, I would understand _boasting_ to mean that what X is talking about is true enough, but I shouldn’t let it get to me; whereas I would understand _bragging_ to at least imply that I shouldn’t listen to X because half the stuff he’s bragging about isn’t even true.

Comment: @oerkelens and JanusBahsJacquet: That actually helped my understanding of these words quite a lot, why didn't you write it as an answer? I would have upvoted them both since they're useful.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I make no such distinction. Bragging is not confined to things that aren't true, not at all. We speak of winning a game for "bragging rights," which would not be available did we not win, etc.

Comment: @Robusto I never said it was. I just said _brag_ is _more likely_ than _boast_ to be used of nonfactual b***s, which it is to me (and if you look at Sven’s reply, that fits too). But of course both verbs can be used in both senses.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it's any more likely, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the discussion of *boast* versus *brag* in *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942):

> **boast,** *v.* **Boast**, **brag**, **vaunt**, **crow**, **gasconade** agree in meaning to give vent in speech to one's pride in oneself (or one's family, one's connections, one's race, one's accomplishments, or the like). ... Boast is the general term; it may or may not carry a suggestion of contempt, or impute exaggeration, ostentation, vaingloriousness, or the like, to the boaster; [examples omitted]. Brag is more colloquial than  boast, and carries a stronger implication of  exaggeration and conceit; it often also implies glorying in one's superiority, or in what one can do as well as in what one is, or has, or has done. [Examples omitted.]

S.I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word* (1968) puts *boast* and *brag* in a group with *crow*, *gloat*, *pride*, *strut*, and *vaunt*:

> These words refer to feelings of self-congratulation. **Boast** may suggest justifiable self-satisfaction: a college that *boasts* an unusually high number of distinguished alumni.More oftn, however, the word suggests a self-important and tasteless pointing out of one's own successes [examples omitted]. Occasionally the word can refer to self-congratulation for a victory not yet won: He *boasted* that he would finish off the challenger in the first round. ...
>
> **Brag** intensifies the note of tastelessness in *boast*, suggesting limitless conceit and, possibly, inaccuracy of the claims being made: [examples omitted].

A usage note in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) suggests that the Merriam-Webster view of *boast* and *brag* has evolved somewhat since 1942:

> BOAST often suggests ostentation and exaggeration [example omitted], but it may imply a claiming with proper and justifiable pride [example omitted]. BRAG suggests crudity and artlessness in glorifying oneself [example omitted].

The general sense I get from these efforts to distinguish between the two terms is that, although both may be used in some instances to describe unjustifiable self-promotion, *boast* occasionally appears in connection with some objectively valid basis for high self-regard, whereas *brag* is almost without exception used in the context of crude self-aggrandizement. Still, I think that most English speakers today consider them to be virtually interchangeable when used in connection with the self-referential utterances of people who suffer from unduly inflated self-regard.